# Expresión regular de 5 numeros separados por comas de entre 1 y 90

Tags: regex

Muy buenas, estoy intentando hacer una expresión regular que me valide una cadena de 5 números de entre 1 y 90 separado por comas

Por ejemplo: 12,12,12,12,12

Mi expresión regular (No me funciona)

```
^([1,9]|[1,8][0,9]|90)(,([1,9]|[1,8][0,9]|90){5})$
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 4):

Para capturar un rango de caracteres debes separarlos con un guión, y no con una coma. Es decir, `[1-9]` en lugar de `[1,9]` (esta segunda forma sólo encajará con el 1 o el 9, pero no con dígitos intermedios).

Por otro lado el operador `{5}` para indicar que el elemento anterior se repita 5 veces, se refiere sólo al número, y no a la coma que también debería repetirse, aunque la última vez no hay coma.

Creo que puede ser más sencillo hacer algo como lo siguiente.

- Llamemos "numero-valido" a cualquiera entre 1 y 90. La expresión regular que tú buscabas que encaja con un "número-válido" era `[1-9]|[1-8][0-9]|90`.

  Alternativamente se me ocurre esta otra: `[1-8][0-9]?|9|90` pues define un dígito entre 1 y 8 seguido opcionalmente de otro entre 0 y 9. Eso nos cubre todos los números deseados, salvo el 9 y el 90 que añado luego con un "or"

  Cualquiera de estas dos opciones son válidas para definir un "numero-valido".
- La expresión completa para "cinco números válidos separados por comas" sería algo del estilo: `((numero-valido),){4}(numero-valido)`. Es decir, la secuencia de un número válido seguido de coma, todo ello repetido cuatro veces, y seguido de un quinto número válido.

Finalmente los paréntesis que usamos para agrupar expresiones serán considerados como "grupos de captura". Si no estamos interesados en capturar grupos, podemos usar `(?:` en lugar de `(`.

Así pues, propongo esta expresión:

```
^(?:(?:[1-8][0-9]?|9|90),){4}(?:[1-8][0-9]?|9|90)$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/abOYSB/1)

Answer (score 0):

Tengo un conflicto con los números que puedan ser de la forma 01,..,09 ya que no sé si quieres abarcarlos.

En ese caso, la expresión:

```
^((0?[1-9]|[1-8]\d|90),){4}(0?[1-9]|[1-8]\d|90)$
```

funciona bastante bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]